# azure DevOps basic Auth using HttpClient (FAILED)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, dotnet-httpclient, azure-devops-rest-api

i am trying to Authenticate using HttpClient to my Azure Dev organization.
but its always failed.

the only way to achieve success with authentication was using Client Library like this:

```
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl), new VssClientCredentials());
```

hope someone can tell me what is it the proper way to auth using username and password only.

UPDATE: 
i also tried like this:

```
        string SecurelyStoredUserName = "EmailAddressAsUserName";
        SecureString SecurelyStoredPassword = new SecureString();

        string PWD = "MyVerySecuredPassword";
        PWD.ToList().ForEach(SecurelyStoredPassword.AppendChar);

        NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(
        SecurelyStoredUserName, SecurelyStoredPassword, azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl);


        string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SecurelyStoredUserName + ":" + SecurelyStoredPassword));

        HttpClientHandler handler;
        handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = myCred };
        HttpClient client;
        client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(azureDevOpsOrganizationUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
```

that what i did, but when i tried to do a get/post , i get Error 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Can you share what did you try with `HttpClient`?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk yes, i edited my post

Comment: Are you using your password or personal access token? Azure DevOps accepts PAT rather than your password. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#q-how-can-i-use-a-pat-in-my-code

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT yes thanks you all for the help, I just did it with PAT and it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send a network credential to Azure Devops. It doesn't accept that kind of authentication. You could use a Personal Access token, or use the Active Directory API to get access.

[All is explained on the very first "Getting started" pages on how to use the Azure DevOps APIs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#create-the-request)

A [complete sample for Interactive User+Pass auth is available here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample).

If you're trying to act as a user on-behalf-of, then you may need to rethink your approach.